# How would I solve this ordinary differential equation in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following metric:$$ds^2=i^2(c+A\space t)^2dt^2+\left(\frac{2+z}{2(1+z)}\right)^2dr^2\tag 1$$In Mathematica, how would I solve for r(t)?  I can assume that $ds^2=0$.  Also, $c$, $A$ are constants, and $z$ does not change with $t$ or $r$. So I know analytically that I can do this:$$0=-(c+A\space t)^2dt^2+\left(\frac{2+z}{2(1+z)}\right)^2dr^2$$$$(c+A\space t)^2dt^2=\left(\frac{2+z}{2(1+z)}\right)^2dr^2$$$$\frac{(c+A\space t)^2}{\left(\frac{2+z}{2(1+z)}\right)^2}=\frac{dr^2}{dt^2}$$Assuming all values are real, we can take the square root:$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{2(c+A\space t)(1+z)}{2+z}$$Then the distance, $r$, is simply the integral over $t$:$$r(t)=\int\frac{2(c+A\space t)(1+z)}{2+z}dt$$$$r(t)=\frac{2(c\space t+A\space t^2)(1+z)}{2+z}$$So here's my question.  I know I can do this analytically, but it seems to me that this is, essentially, an ODE.  Is there any way to coerce Mathematica into using something like DSolve on Eq. (1) to solve this for me automatically?

**Edit:** The main problem I have conceptually is that $dt$ and $dr$ are infinitesimals in the original formula.  Analytically, I can arrive at an expression of $\frac{dr}{ds}$.  What I can't do is make the leap to tell Mathematica that $\frac{dr}{ds}$ is D[r, t].  If we can do this, then it's simple to have DSolve figure this out.

Comment: What are  `A ` and `z`? Functions or constants?

Comment: Can't you rename $dr^2$ as `r'(t)^2` and use `dt -> 1`?

Comment: Yes, I can, if I analyze the equation.  I'm looking for an answer where I don't have to get involved.  Not all the metrics will be this obvious.  I'm looking for a solution where Mathematica derives $r(t)$ from the metric.  Again, my instincts tell me this is an ODE problem.

Comment: I expect that this isn't satisfactory `Simplify[Integrate[dr[t]/dt/.Solve[0==I^2(c+At)^2dt^2+((2+z)/(2(1+z)))^2dr[t]^2,dr[t]],t],z\[Element]Reals]`.  In order to figure out what rules are needed to do this procedure automatically, a more complicated metric and/or a fuller description of the analytic justification of these steps would be useful.

Comment: @Adam - Thank you.  That's a fine simplification of the analytical solution.  Am I wrong to believe this can be solved using an ODE solver?  I want $r(t)$ from an equation that forms a relation between $dt$ and $dr$.  It looks like it has all the ingredients.

Comment: The code `Simplify@DSolve[{Dt[s]^2==-(c+A t[s])^2Dt[t[s],s]^2+((2+z)/(2(1+z)))^2Dt[r[s],s]^2,Dt[t[s],s]==1},{r[s],t[s]},s]` produces results.  This creates a parameterization of $r(s),t(s)$ which might be solved for $r(t)$.  So far my attempts at doing this are nasty.  Doing a `Activate[%,Integrate]` takes a very long time but may be a good first step.

Comment: @Adam - That's very much in the spirit of the question.  If you figure out the last step, please post it.  Something like this would work for any metric I throw it it.

Comment: @Adam - Why did you assume that Dt[t[s], s] == 1?

Comment: Consider $(t^2,t^2)$ and $(t,t)$.  These both describe $x(t)=y(t)$.  Asserting $dt=1$ fixes a particular parameterization so that Mathematica can actually solve for something.  Asserting $dt=2$ or any other function of $s$ should yield the same relationship between $r$ and $t$ (although different choices may result in more difficult simplifications).